# Google-places-api - there is no country in response

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm working with `Google-places-api` in my project.

User finds a city using `places-autocomplete` and the city (place_id) is stored in the database. Then they can see for example Countries they visited. The problem is with some cities or localities.

If I choose city `Dakhla`, which is in `Morocco` resp. `Western Sahara`, it doesn't return any country. It returns this json with address `Dakhla 73000`.

This is my request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJQ2KgOjlIIgwRcgFf7vLbciU&key=

And the response, you can clearly see there is no such thing like country:

```
{
  "html_attributions": [

  ],
  "result": {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "Dakhla",
        "short_name": "Dakhla",
        "types": [
          "locality",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "73000",
        "short_name": "73000",
        "types": [
          "postal_code"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "adr_address": "<span class=\"locality\">Dakhla</span> <span class=\"postal-code\">73000</span>",
    "formatted_address": "Dakhla 73000",
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 23.7221111,
        "lng": -15.9347384
      },
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 23.7557101,
          "lng": -15.9082891
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 23.6551306,
          "lng": -15.982863
        }
      }
    },
    "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
    "id": "4617ad02ab8faa18c1fbfa0d4ad6912184fd5d96",
    "name": "Dakhla",
    "photos": [
      {
        "height": 3456,
        "html_attributions": [
          "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/101097515652901724856/photos\">Anass eagles</a>"
        ],
        "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAA2Yed-VeeRRlwAFsiydbMubthP2DKraqL9h2Jm942UZDxlu2WQ7ZgLjOjHC3PaYqMuXsK7r2-pmxxRgFBjXvrgNBp5PzeVatbwZSQF5TGcdc-cqmdJZXMy-4xqaUD6eQ8EhBGXM0WrdBeM510nkZF2pr3GhSqU0hYlKDx7cAT_tLDUAXQpm3SFw",
        "width": 5184
      },
      {
        "height": 482,
        "html_attributions": [
          "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115265998372124547858/photos\">AN OU AR</a>"
        ],
        "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAkrItWe0tbch3zTtrTp7VHbNDT9RiZJtq0QBIGc2RHSTgNMHSRWkZ8ZtEC01-CmKCiSRf3AMlEcSTKuEKGuYZMKATIdTxWbwl6NoCle0xza9dW1_4GteLk5UaAaMZOxQ-EhDhG7HOlzFQKiWbcrx_RzIBGhRrFjrqxXA5iO4rlenGjaQC-dvmQQ",
        "width": 1280
      },
      {
        "height": 2848,
        "html_attributions": [
          "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109340304984953152070/photos\">Laasri Photo</a>"
        ],
        "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAw2NU-MmFfu4xeu42AbUwZfQq9YXvbfXuK6QBCl0651gO-EKW_4SUsM3jSA6TP277sAG77dNsZjoHZ9huVvyzuWyuGupf_49YHuTQIRVxXIXFuzKt8FicASPQ26QqET3XEhBkc5FudE60iEM8QMR5IV5aGhSfAm96l2t19ckVKMAna6dXG0MDwQ",
        "width": 4288
      }
    ],
    "place_id": "ChIJQ2KgOjlIIgwRcgFf7vLbciU",
    "reference": "CmRbAAAA6wvlR94FGET4itrDJ8zgThYhbU2uL4BVphEIKqkdXNpqigNTScX46GqylfK6x2_ETIhYFutmjN3eCIQzFsVHYJYX9n2nHycVa0AxwyJizPrnvFYAIiD8fO_Ib66TJTJoEhBLFH5SDZDZ9DTJuqKkHZsyGhTqn0loCaR8uHfVc1NfeNOMXaiTEQ",
    "scope": "GOOGLE",
    "types": [
      "locality",
      "political"
    ],
    "url": "https://maps.google.com/?q=Dakhla+73000&ftid=0xc2248393aa06243:0x2572dbf2ee5f0172",
    "utc_offset": 0,
    "vicinity": "Dakhla"
  },
  "status": "OK"
}
```

What would you do? The country is very important for us.

**EDIT:**

The only thing which comes to my mind is to try to get country and if there is no such information, use it's coordinates and try another service like `OpenStreetMaps` but I would like to avoid working with two different servicies.

Comment: Do you have other examples? Is it possible that they are in a [disputed territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_disputes)?

Comment: Western Sahara is on the list.

Comment: I get similar results rather frequently. As example is with the coordinates 33.73718, 75.154686